# Using group by with multiple fields

Tags: mysql, postgresql

SELECT release_year, country, MAX(budget) AS max_budget,
FROM films
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY release_year;

I cant tell what is wrong with the above query as it keeps returning error

I have looked for errors in spelling. I have also checked the field names against the data.

Comment: Please add the error message in full and review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: It looks like you have an extra comma, just before your `FROM`

Comment: also, you are grouping by country but selecting release_year, and there are likely more than one release_year for each country; which do you want?  make it min(release_year) or max(release_year) (in the select and order by) or change to `group by country, release_year`